# The local variable rootcreat may not have been initialized

Tags: java

I am trying to return an Object of  my custom class `Rootcreator` but I am getting this error `The local variable rootcreat may not have been initialized` how can I initialize an custom class I have already initialized it. How can I get it to work to enable the `join_line` method to return this costum Object?

I appreciate any help.

```
private static RootCreator join_line(String path, String key) {
    RootCreator  rootcreat;
     .
     .
     .
     .
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(path + File.separator
            + newName);

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
        ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            buffer.add(line);

        }
        ArrayList<String> bufferDirection = new ArrayList<String>();

        String direction = bufferDirection.get(0);
        String route = bufferDirection.get(1);
        String day = bufferDirection.get(2);
        String startString = bufferDirection.get(3);
        String[] startStringSplitt = startString.split(":");
        String firstPart = startStringSplitt[0];
        String otherDirection = firstPart.substring(0,
                firstPart.length() - 2);


        bufferDirection.clear();
        LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> first = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
        LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> second = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

        for (String keyLine : direcList) {
            if (keyLine.startsWith("New direction")) {
                int index = direcList.indexOf(keyLine);
                List<String> firstDirec = direcList.subList(0, index);
                List<String> secondtDirec = direcList.subList(index,
                        direcList.size() - 1); // This part wih New
                                                // Direction.

                ArrayList<String> timeListFirst = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (String mergeLine : firstDirec) {
                    if (!(mergeLine.equals(direction))
                            && !(mergeLine.equals(route))
                            && !(mergeLine.equals(day))) {
                        timeListFirst.add(mergeLine);

                    }
                }
                first = merge_table(timeListFirst);

                ArrayList<String> timeListSecond = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (String mergeLine : secondtDirec) {
                    otherDirection = otherDirection.trim();

                    if (!(mergeLine.equals(otherDirection))
                            && !(mergeLine.equals(route))
                            && !(mergeLine.equals(day))
                            && !(mergeLine.equals("New direction"))) {

                        timeListSecond.add(mergeLine);

                    }
                }
                 second = merge_table(timeListSecond);

            }

        }

      rootcreat = new RootCreator(first, second, route, day, direction, otherDirection);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //The error is here.
    return rootcreat;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
RootCreator  rootcreat = null;
```

If your code (as written) throws `FileNotFoundException`, `rootcreat` will remain not initialized.

Please note that `local` references (unlike `class` variables) are not initialized by default.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `rootcreat` may not have been initialized because it's only initialized in the last line of the `try` block.  If an exception is thrown before that point, then nothing will initialize `rootcreat`.  Then the variable is referenced in the `return` statement before it's guaranteed to be initialized, and the compiler returns an error.

Move the return statement into the `try` block, immediately after `rootcreat` is initialized.  But what will be returned if an exception is thrown?  Here, nothing should be returned.  The exception should be thrown from the method.  This method shouldn't be handling the exception `FileNotFoundException`; it should be reporting it.  Remove the `catch` block, and add `throws FileNotFoundException` to the method declaration.  This way, either `rootcreat` is created and returned, or an exception is thrown and the caller will need to catch it.